# Image Automatically Resized In Run-time But Not On Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, rendering

Alright, this is struggling me by now. I have a PNG image which has the size of 10x36px. 
When I try to use that in any of my views it gets resized. Not the frame property, this one remains intact. But visually the image is not the same.

The real image is like this [image: this]. (Sorry if you can barely see it. That's because it has a white background on a white foreground).

But when I am in the simulator (it happens on a device too) it looks like this.

[image: this].

I'm not using contraints(I turned off AutoLayout in order to find the bug).

I printed the frame of that button and it's width, height, x and y values are just as they are in the interface builder. And I printed them everywhere and in response to different events too(I know, that's not the reason. I'm just desperate).

This happens only with this PNG specifically cause other UIButton I have in the very same view, but with differents Images, are working just fine.

What could be the cause of this error?

EDIT:

Trying as a background image it got better. But still not perfect.

[image: this]

Comment: I don't understand what you *want* it to look like...

Comment: Well, those three little lines that composes the image are larger than the one shown in the simulator. Agree?

Comment: Well I don't know, but the only problem I have with the simulator image is that it's thinner than standard. I think most would expect it to have a square aspect.

Comment: In that case the image got smaller in height. Note that that doesn't happen exclusively on the simulator. On my iPhone too.

Comment: When you say you turned off Autolayout, do you mean you unchecked the box in the SB in IB? Also Do you have only one SB?

Comment: I do mean that. I do have only one.

Comment: Are you using xcassets? So are you saying that if you run on the same device, in the same location, a non-png and a png image, they behave differently? Are you setting the image as a button image or background image?

Comment: I'm not using xcassets. Well, not for this particular png. It's not the extension the matters actually. Is how the image is composed. Like, if that was an image of an elipse it would look just fine. It's a UIButton with a Image. Not background image.

Comment: Can you try as a background image?

Comment: It looks like the button is a button on a UINavigationBar? Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Are you using UIButton inside custom view in UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: @Harry it's a UIButton inside a UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 3):

Place the png image inside an empty 36x36 png image in Photoshop/Pixelmator to stop it resizing and preserve the original ratio.

Or try setting the views content mode to "aspect fit" in Interface Builder or programmatically:

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

The cause could be that UIBarButtons treat images differently than UIButtons. UIBarButtons are typically used in UINavigationBars or UIToolbars while UIButtons are used typically in the View.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using Button background image and not Button image.

Button background image covers the whole button background.

Button image places the images on a portion of the background.

Also, use xcassets. It comes with the project template. If you don't have it (deleted it), add a new one and create an image set. Once you do that, add your images. Make sure to select "Render as original image" for each image in your image set.

Answer (score 1):

The PNG image you linked to isn't 10x36 pixels, but 10x30. Oops?

Comment: Why is this an answer?

Comment: If you display an image in a frame of mismatched dimensions, stretching occurs.

Comment: That's just 6 pixels. IMO, my image is too shrinked to say that it lacks only 6 pixels. It lacks much more than that.

Comment: As a first step I would try to use a background image with dimensions that match exactly your frame size.

Comment: Tried that. Same thing.